# Lounge access when flying from Chongqing to Hong Kong?

Tags: transit, lounges

I will soon be connecting via Chongqing (CKG) to Hong Kong on Air China, and would like to chill out at a Star Alliance lounge while I do so.  If [Wikipedia is to be believed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chongqing_Jiangbei_International_Airport), I will be both arriving and departing from Terminal 3A: the catch is that my arrival is on a domestic flight, while the flight out to HK is considered "international".

**Is there a lounge I can use?**  The [Star Alliance lounge finder tells me](https://www.staralliance.com/lounge-finder?t=1529929752482) there are four lounges available, although I'm fairly sure three of these are lies (T1 is no longer operating and Air China has moved out of T2).

Comment: From experience in similar Chinese airports (Chengdu, Shenzhen, Shantou, etc...), there will be ONE Air China lounge, and a lousy one at that. Since you're connecting to an international flight, chances are you'll be in the right place. Domestic flights usually have very few amenities in China.

Comment: It may not matter here, but are you seeking an invitation by virtue of *Gold, COS, or club membership?

Comment: @choster Star Alliance.  Given that my layover is pretty short (3 hours), I'm personally unlikely to pay for access to other lounges, but happy to accept any answers about alternatives if *A is confirmed not to be an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm tickled pink to confirm that ***yes***, there is a lounge on the international side of CKG!  It's creatively called the "International First & Business Class Lounge" and you can find it in Terminal 3A after security & immigration, between gates H4/5:

[image]

It's also *much* better equipped than your average domestic Chinese lounge, with not just the usual assortment of dry snacks, but free wine, beer, soft drinks, fruits, yoghurt:

[image]

In addition, if you're lucky enough to find yourself here during meal hours (6:30-9 AM, 11:30 AM-2 PM, 5:30-8 PM), not only is there a hot meal buffet, but a little counter dishing out [Chongqing noodles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chongqing_noodles) made to order!  I ordered mine 不太辣 and they were still murderously spicy, ask for yours local style if you dare...

[image]
[image]

One important potential catch: this is **not** an official Star Alliance lounge, but just a lounge that airports contract with.  We checked in at Chongqing for our economy-class flights to HKG and were given lounge passes *at check-in* when we waved our Gold cards, but if you connect through here and don't have a lounge pass in hand, you may not be so lucky.  (FWIW, there was another pay-per-use lounge as well nearby, but we didn't investigate further.)